# Window.location doesn't work after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Window.location doesn't work after a success respond when it  call a ajax request, the success function it called.

when i execute on firefox on debugger step by step the window.location  it works .

```
function login(){

var jason ={"usuario":document.getElementById("inputusuario").value,
        "password": document.getElementById("inputpassword").value
           };
            json =JSON.stringify(jason);

          console.log(json);

var onSuccess = function (data) {
    console.log('Success');
    window.location ='salas.html'

};
var onError = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
    alert("no se conecto");

};

var onBeforeSend = function () {
    console.log("Loading");
};

var jason ={"usuario":document.getElementById("inputusuario").value,
        "password": document.getElementById("inputpassword").value
           };

            json =JSON.stringify(jason);
$.ajax({

    url: "../reservaciones/index.php/login",
    type:"POST",
     data: json,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    beforeSend: onBeforeSend,
    error: onError,
    success: onSuccess
 });
};
```

Comment: You mean you see 'Success' in the console but the location isn't changed ?

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? Does it direct you to a page you weren't expecting?

Comment: Why use ajax if your going to go to another page anyway?

Comment: @JackMarchetti  the window.location command its executed but dosent redirect.

Comment: @Musa because i want to compare the credential before change the page. its for a login.

Comment: Sounds safe and secure...

Comment: @dystroy yes I see the Success on the console but the location isn't changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code exactly, added the appropriate elements, and it worked just fine.

This is your code, as is: <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Try these:

**1.** Try `window.location.assign()`. This has been known to fix this very problem.

**2.** Try running `async: true`. From your code I see no reason why you'd want to run `false` and sometimes that can cause timing issues.

Comment: i try window.location.assign() and doesn't work but searching the web i uses this function event.preventDefault(); and it works only in chrome but firefox dont recognize the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the trailing ';' in

window.location ='salas.html'